# check of the atom if it's the last element of the list in Scheme

Tags: scheme, lisp

im trying to solve a question which is to check weather the element x is the last element of the list 

my try is :

```
(Define (last x L)
  (Cond 
    ((NULL? (cdr L)) (EQ? x (car L)) #T )
    (else (last x (cdr L)))))
```

but I think there is something wrong . Please could you help me with that ?

 thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be the correct version:

```
(define (last? elt lst)
  (cond
    ((null? lst)       #f)
    ((null? (cdr lst)) (eq? elt (car lst)))
    (else              (last? elt (cdr lst)))))
```

- you need to check for the empty list as well
- `(eq? x (car lst))` already yields a boolean, no need to add `#t`
- Scheme is case-sensitive, you need to pay attention to this
- in Scheme, names of predicates (procedures returning true or false) end with a question mark
- `x` is not a very expressive name, and it is not usual to use capital letters such as `L`; easy to understand variable names would be `elt` (for "element") and `lst` (for "list")
- also, indentation is important for readability, your editor should help you indent properly

The procedure could also simply be written as

```
(define (last? elt lst)
  (if (null? lst)
      #f
      (eq? elt (car (reverse lst)))))
```

or even shorter:

```
(define (last? elt lst)
  (and (not (null? lst))
       (eq? elt (car (reverse lst)))))
```

Comment: that's great but i'm getting an error executing it with variable empty? is not bound . I have replaced empty with NULL and same error

Comment: And, pay attention to use lower-case letters!

Comment: I like the use of the boolean connectives in the last version;  I think it would be good to show something similar for the first case, too:  `(and (not (null? lst)) (or (and (null? (rest lst)) (eq? elt (first lst))) (last? elt (rest lst))))`.  The `reverse` copies the whole list, and there's really no reason to do _any_ memory allocation in this.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor I did it for the second example only because it reads naturally: "the list is not empty and elt is the last element of the list (a.k.a. the first element of the reversed list)". Not sure that the and/or cascade would have made things clearer for the OP in the first example.

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor As for using `reverse` - you are right, of course. I like to stretch the examples a bit, by giving an alternative or a Racket version. Performance is rarely my point, but I rather want to present a different perspective. Most of these beginner questions are from students so I think perspective is more important than performance at that point.

Comment: I agree that it's important to make sure the questions are simple enough that beginners can understand them, but I do think it's important to show that it's possible to do things efficiently (time wise, space wise, etc.) in Scheme.  Too many people get just a bare exposure in university and leave thinking that it's an awkward inefficient language, but (as you and I know) that's simply not true. :)